# If we expand or reduce the layer of the same model, can we still be able to train from pretrained model in Pytorch?

Tags: python, model, pytorch, torch

If the pretrained model such as Resnet101 were trained on ImageNet dataset, then I change some layers inside it. Can I still be able to use the pretrained model on different ABC dataset?

Lets say This is ResNet34 Model,
[image]

It is pretrained on ImageNet and saved as **ResNet.pt** file.

If I changed some layers inside it, lets say I made it more deeper by introducing some layers in conv4_x (check image)

```
model = Resnet34() #I have changes some layers inside this ResNet34()

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.00005)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('Resnet.pt')['state_dict']) #This is pretrained model of ResNet before some changes
optimizer.load_state_dict(torch.load('Resnet.pt')['optimizer'])
```

Can I do this? or there are anyother method?

Comment: "If I changed some layers inside it, lets say I made it more deeper by introducing some layers in conv4_x (check image)" how exactly did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything you like - the question is: would it be better than training from scratch?

Here are a few issues you might encounter:

**1. A mismatch between weights saved in `ResNet.pt` (the trained weights of the original ResNet18) and the `state_dict` of your modified model.**
You would probably need to manually make sure that the old weights are correctly assigned to the original layers and only the new layer is not initialized.

**2. Initializing the weights of the new layer.**
Since you are training a resNet - you can take advantage of the residual connections and init the weights of the new layer such that it would initially make no contribution to the predicted value and only pass the input directly to the output via the residual link.

Comment: Yes, the weights will be mismatched. Lets say I changed single layer, that layer yields output of [64,3,3,3] and in the pretrained model there will be no such layer, this [64,3,3,3] will not mismatch with it. To match that layer I would have to create the array with random weights of [64,3,3,3] and make it not count for the contribution in prediction in initial layers, this is what you want me to do? Then the with next backpropagation it will be trained based on the previous operations?